# Ошибка биндинга - приходит пустая модель

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть два метода для редактирования

Первый передает значения для редактирования, а второй редактирует

```
public ActionResult EditMagazine(int id)
{
    var editMagazineModel = new EditMagazineViewModel()
    {
        Magazine = magazineService.EditMagazine(id)
    };
    return View(editMagazineModel);
}
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult EditMagazine1(EditMagazineViewModel magazine)
{
    var magazineModel = new Magazine
    {
        MagazineId = magazine.Magazine.MagazineId,
        Name = magazine.Magazine.Name,
        Number = magazine.Magazine.Number,
        YearOfPublishing = magazine.Magazine.YearOfPublishing
    };
    magazineService.EditMagazine1(magazineModel);
    return RedirectToAction("Magazine");
}
```

из-за того что делаю ViewModel пришлось столкнуться с mapping'ом ,

так вот проблема в том что во втором методе выходит исключение из-за этого

```
var magazineModel = new Magazine
 {
```

я создаю новый обьект

Кто подскажет как правильно передать значения с первого метода для второго метода

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
```

Вот ViewModel

```
public class EditMagazineViewModel
{
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }       
}
```

а вот Model

```
public class Magazine
{
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
}
```

Вот View EditMagazine

```
@model Library.ViewModel.MagazineViewModel.EditMagazineViewModel

@{
Layout = "~/Views/Home/Layout.cshtml";
}

 <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style-form.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("EditMagazine1", "Magazine"))

   {

       @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Magazine</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Magazine.MagazineId)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Magazine.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Magazine.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Magazine.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Magazine.Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Magazine.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Magazine.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Magazine.YearOfPublishing, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Magazine.YearOfPublishing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Magazine.YearOfPublishing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Покажите код класса `Magazine`

Comment: текст исключения?

Comment: Вы точку останова на начало метода поставьте и проверьте не приходит ли пустым ваш `EditMagazineViewModel magazine`

Comment: @AK я ошибся и показал не ту ViewModel ,я уже исправил

Comment: @Bulson я проверил через Debug мне приходит пустой ,вот в чем вопрос ,как передать журнал с первого метода во второй

Comment: Явных ошибок не вижу, должно работать именно так. А попробуйте мой вариант (см. ответ) - убрать лишний слой во ViewModel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ваша модель основана на простых типах типа int и string:

```
public class Magazine
{
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
}
```

При этом вы могли пойти [по пути использования модели в качестве ViewModel](http://blog.byndyu.ru/2012/05/viewmodel-domain-model.html) - но раз уж вы пошли по пути ухода от модели - то не надо было во вьюмодели ссылаться на доменную логику:

```
public class EditMagazineViewModel
{
    public Magazine Magazine { get; set; }       
}
```

Сделайте класс на простых типах:

```
public class EditMagazineViewModel
{
    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
}
```

(Чувствуете, что хочется записаться в сторонники использования моделей в качестве вьюмоделей? Код копипастится)

Давайте теперь переделаем наш первый action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var magazine = magazineService.GetById(id);
    var model = new EditMagazineViewModel(magazine);
    return View(model);
}
```

и второй:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(EditMagazineViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        return this.View(model);

    var magazine = model.ToEntity();
    magazineService.Update(magazine);
    return RedirectToAction("Magazine");
}
```

(Обратите внимание: в сервис мы передаём уже доменную модель, сервис относится к слою бизнес-логики и может ничего не знать о десятках приложений (веб, мобильных) у каждого свои собственные вьюмодели)

Только для этого нам нужно класс модели переписать следующим образом:

```
public class EditMagazineViewModel
{
    public EditMagazineViewModel()
    {
    }

    public EditMagazineViewModel(Magazine magazine)
    {
        this.MagazineId = magazine.MagazineId;
        this.Name = magazine.Name;
        this.Number = magazine.Number;
        this.YearOfPublishing = magazine.YearOfPublishing;
    }

    public Magazine ToEntity()
    {
        return new Magazine
        {
            MagazineId = this.MagazineId,
            Name = this.Name,
            Number = this.Number,
            YearOfPublishing = this.YearOfPublishing,
        };
    }

    public int MagazineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }
}
```

Первый конструктор нужен для asp.net, второй - для нас (чтобы не разбухал метод контроллера), а ToEntity - преобразует обратно ViewModel в Model.

Понадобится - можете потом подтащить мапперы вместо этих методов.

Остаётся переписать view:

```
@model Library.ViewModel.MagazineViewModel.EditMagazineViewModel
@{
    Viewbag.Title = "Edit magazine";
}
<h2>@Viewbag.Title</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("EditMagazine", "Magazine", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MagazineId)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

У меня в тестовом приложении работает (естественно чуть другие неймспейсы), проблем нет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо ,это работает

Comment: в своем примере изменил имя magazine на model и проблема тоже решилась

Comment: @Simon Любопытно, но непонятно: не должно это было повлиять.