# При одном и том же действии приходят разные результаты Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Делаю связь многие ко многим и при добавлении новой книги мне либо приходят поля самой книги ,но не приходят id издательств которые пытаюсь привязать ,либо не приходят поля ,а приходят id издательств . А разница лишь в том что меняю имя .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как вы видите если у меня имя model ,то приходят поля

а сейчас я поменяю имя на book

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и у меня приходят id издательств, хотя ввожу все тоже самое

Вот моя ViewModel

```
public class AddBookViewModel
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public int YearOfPublishing { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<PublicationHouses> PublicationHouses { get; set; }

    public ICollection<int> SelectedPublicationHouses { get; set; }

    public AddBookViewModel()
    {
        PublicationHouses = new List<PublicationHouses>();
        SelectedPublicationHouses = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

Если будет нужно ,то пришлю саму View

я не понимаю почему из-за того что я меняю имя мне приходят разные результаты , и может кто-то подсказать как сделать так чтоб приходили и поля книги и издательства

Если нужна подробная информация и чего-то не хватает ,пишите - я добавлю

P.S был до этого похожий вопрос у меня  [Ошибка биндинга - приходит пустая модель](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/812486/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C/812597#812597)

я поменял в своем вопросе имя magazine на model и проблема решилась

Вот View

```
@model Library.ViewModel.BookViewModels.AddBookViewModel

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddBook";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/style-form.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,300" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/styles/kendo.material.mobile.min.css" />

<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2017.3.1026/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    {

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li class="active">@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Home", "Home") <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></li>
                <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("All Publications", "AllPublications", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Books", "Book", "Book")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Magazines", "Magazine", "Magazine")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Brochures", "Brochure", "Brochure")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Publication Houses", "PublicationHouse", "PublicationHouse")</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                <li><a href="">Nav item again</a></li>
                <li><a href="">One more nav</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Another nav item</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
            <div class="row placeholders">
                @using (Html.BeginForm("AddBook", "Book"))
                {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    <div class="form-horizontal">
                        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Add new book</h2>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearOfPublishing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <label for="publicationHouses">@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublicationHouses)</label>
                        <select id="required" name="Book.SelectedPublicationHouses" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select Publication houses">
                            @foreach (var publicationHouse in Model.PublicationHouses)
                            {
                                <option value="@publicationHouse.PublicationHousesId">@publicationHouse.Name</option>
                            }
                        </select>
                        <script>
                            $(document).ready(function () {
                                var required = $("#required").kendoMultiSelect().data("kendoMultiSelect");
                            });
                        </script>
                        <button class="k-button" id="get">Add new item</button>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `Если будет нужно ,то пришлю саму View` очевидно, нужно

Comment: @tym32167 добавил

Comment: Ещё код вставляйте текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: вот это вам ни о чем не говорит? `name="Book.SelectedPublicationHouses"` Да и вообще странный способ создания селекта, как насчет Html.DropDownFor()?

Comment: @tym32167 картинкой вставил чтоб показать что в debug происходит, а странный способ потому что нужно именно через kendomultiselect

Comment: 1) Когда вы пишите `name="Book.SelectedPublicationHouses"` - это означает, что значения будут биндиться на параметр с названием book, потому когда меняете его на что то другое, биндиться значения перестают

Comment: 2) Делайте свои кендоселекты через Html.DropDownFor(), этому вроде ничего не мешает, это же обычный селект с доп аттрибутом

Comment: Плюс один к штатным хелперам. Я правда посмотрю только завтра пример.

Comment: @tym32167 хорошо ,сейчас попробую

Comment: @AK спасибо ,буду признателен

Comment: Какая-то подозрительная у вас вьюмодель. Она у вас что и в DataSet сразу задействована? Зачем `virtual` у `PublicationHouses`? И где во вьюмодели атрибуты `Data Annotations`? Где проверка вьюмодели на валидность в экшен методах контроллера? Чёт вы не то пишите.